# Axios keeps sending GET to wrong endpoint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I configured axios to send request to my express backend running at localhost:8081

src/htpp/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
})
```

Then in a vue component I send a post request to post form data

src/components/create-list.vue

```
import http from '../http'

http.request({
  url: 'lists',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    displayName: this.displayName,
    listName: this.listName,
    userEmail: this.userEmail
  }
})
```

When I submit my form the following request is sent

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/?list-name=Test&user-email=test%40test.de&user-name=Test

Request Method: GET

I was expecting

Request URL : http://localhost:8081/api/lists

Request Method : POST

Request body : {"list-name": "Test", "user-email": "test@test.d", "user-name": "Test"}

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: It's working for me (if I inline http in the same script). Are you sure something isn't weird with your imports or something else? Can you declare http right next to your call to see if your still reproducing the issue?

Comment: BTW, don't use `http` as a name here, it is a native Node object and it has a 'request()' method. Name your http module something else, e.g. `axiosClient` or something like that.

Comment: Good point @ChadMoore

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem
In my vue component template a button was submiting my form and apparently the default behaviour is to send this GET request (even if it wasn't a type="submit" button)
Either prevent default of the click event or change  balise to  solved the problem
FYI I used Chrome 67.0.3396.99

Comment: It should be pointed out that `<button type="button">submit</button>` does not submit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to import your index.js like this. Make sure your path is correct. 
Also try to change the http name to other name like Chad Moore mentioned.

```
import http from '../http/index'
```

Comment: Thanks, 
My import was correct. Import a directory is equivalent to import the index.js file in it.
As I explained above I found the problem. Chrome was sending the form and my request was ignored.